# How to extract JSON from a multiline string variable in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, string

I have a multiline string variable which includes multiline of system log like below, and I would like to extract the JSON part only

```
System 123456
Logs start 2021-07-03 12:00:00
<event> {log_in_json}
<event> {log_in_json}
```

I using `find` to search over the string variable but this only allow me to get the first occurrence. Anyone could advise?

```
start = var.find(<event>)
end = var.find("}}")
extracted_line = var[start:end+len("}}")]
json_str = extracted_line.lstrip(<event>)
print(json_str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the optional second argument to the `find` method, we can set the starting
point for the search. So, second and following times around, we'll start where
we previously found the last match (`end`), until the method returns -1:

```
var = '''
System 123456
Logs start 2021-07-03 12:00:00
<event> {log_in_json}
<event> {log_in_json2}
'''

start = var.find('<event>')
while start > 0:
    end = var.find("}", start)
    extracted_line = var[start:end+len("}")]
    json_str = extracted_line.lstrip('<event> ')
    print(json_str)
    start = var.find('<event>', end)
# {log_in_json}
# {log_in_json2}
```